# Как закрыть .py из другого .py?

Tags: python, файлы, subprocess

Хочу, чтобы мой код открывал файл *.py* и через некоторое время закрывал его.
Открывать я научился используя `subprocess.call`
А вот закрыть никак не получается : (

```
import time
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call

call(["python", "my_program.py"])
time.sleep(5)
# тут надо закрыть my_program.py
```

Пробовал писать, но это не помогает.

```
file = 'my_program.py'
sys.exit(file)
```

Поискал в интернете, но все равно ничего не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте библиотеку os

```
import os
import time
os.startfile('Степень.py')#Это открыть
time.sleep(2)
os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM py.exe')
```

но тут есть проблема оно закрывает всю действующие файлы питон и самого себя тоже.

Comment: Не сработало, к сожалению

Comment: а как это должно сработать? `os.system()` запускает процесс..

Comment: Сейчас я тут потестил немного вот правильный ответ

Comment: В принципе, если я конвертну эту программу в .exe, то она сама себя не закроет и это решение мне подойдет. Я кстати уже проверил, это работает. Не совсем то решение, но главное что работает) Спасибо!

Comment: А как именно вы это сделаете? Я просто делаю сейчас что то похожее поэтому мне пригодится. Вот ссылка на вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1368545/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%8f